# change width of an element(select box) only if the auto width is more than current width-jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp

It's the super-boring super-annoying IE-select-box issue!

I had solved it successfully...

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
    if($.browser.msie){
        $("select:not(#wrkTimeFrm,#wrkTimeFrm1,#wrkTimeTo,#wrkTimeTo1)")
            .focus(function(){
            $(this).css("width","auto");
            $(this).css("position","absolute");
        });
        $("select:not(#wrkTimeFrm,#wrkTimeFrm1,#wrkTimeTo,#wrkTimeTo1)")
            .blur(function(){
            $(this).css("width","145px");
            $(this).css("position","inherit");
        });
    }
})
```

...but that was only until now.

As you can see the :not(id)s are the select boxes whose size is/should be less than 145px, i.e. it should not change. It was working fine. But the list of such select boxes is way too much to handle that way. Moreover the ids are dynamic and I've no idea whose width is more/less than 145px(the options are dynamic...obviously).

So now, I'm trying to update the width of select box only if the its auto width is more than its current width.
Something like:

```
$(function(){
    if($.browser.msie){
        $("select").focus(function(){
            if(autoWidth>currentWidth){
            do_the_rest();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And I'm running sort of ideas for 'autoWidth' and 'currentWidth'($(".dd").outerWidth() gives the width as 145, but I'm afraid if I can use it for currentWidth as I got more than one select boxes on same jsp with same css class 'dd', although event is fired for 'this' select box only. May be someone could let me know how to get the class name of the select box under focus...maybe!.....and than the outerWidth.).

So please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm finding it really hard to understand what you mean, specially because you didn't include any fiddles or even the generated HTML code... but I think maybe what you want to do is this:

```
$(function(){
    if($.browser.msie){
        $("select").focus(function(){
            if($(this).width()>145){
              $(this).css("width","auto");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$(function() {
    $("select").focus(function() {
        if ($(this).width() > 95) {
            var prevWidth = $(this).width();
            $(this).css("width", "auto");
            if ($(this).width() < 100) {
                $(this).css("width", 100 + "px");
            }
            $(this).blur(function() {
                $(this).css("width", prevWidth + "px");
            });
        }

    });

});​
```

Comment: in sort:the select box width should be set to auto only if setting it to auto increases it's width.
And $(this).width() was returning 'null'/'undefined' in case of select:.not('#id')...
fiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/RKXmT/

Please let me know if I need to be more clearer...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use % for your css width,this issue handels

```
width:80%;
```

Comment: When you set all size by %,any user with any device can see your site with better quality,for example you set main div width:80% and margin:0 auto then use all child div width,by %,for examples first div width:20% and ...